# Using React-dates' DateRangePicker inside of scrolling container

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-dates

Is there an easy way to use a DateRangePicker inside of a scrolling div?
The problem I am facing is that I have a container div that has `overflow-y: scroll` set. When you click on the `DateRangePicker` the calendar that pops up is inside of the scrolling div. This behavior can be seen in this thread: [DateRangePicker](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/273).

I need that calendar to pop up outside of the div in order to make it usable. In the thread linked above there is talk about using Portals, but I dont want the whole component to be attached to another div. I want only the calendar modal to to put outside of the idv.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found was to pass the `withPortal` prop to `DateRangePicker`. This makes it so that the calendar opens centrally on the screen. More information can be found here: [Airbnb React-Dates docs](https://airbnb.io/projects/react-dates/)